# Dados do INNER JOIN misturado no php + json

Tags: php, sql, json, aplicação-web, firebird

Boa noite, então estou tentando criar uma **API**, e me deparei com o seguinte problema, eu não estou conseguindo agrupar os dados do meu `inner join`, segue o código :

```
 <?php
    $json = array();
    $db = 'localhost:C:\baseking\TGA.FDB';
    $username = 'SYSDBA';
    $password = 'masterkey';

    $con = ibase_connect($db, $username, $password);
    $sql = "SELECT TTICKET.idticket, TTICKETPROD.codprd, TPRODUTO.NOMEFANTASIA, TPRODUTO.preco1, TTICKET.idcartao from tticket
    inner join TTICKETPROD on (TTICKETPROD.idticket = TTICKET.IDTICKET)
    inner join TPRODUTO on (TTICKETPROD.codprd = tproduto.codprd)where TTICKET.status = 'A' ";
    $rc = ibase_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 

        // print_r($row);
        // echo json_encode($row);

        $json['CODPRD'][] = $row -> CODPRD;
        $json['IDTICKET'][] = $row -> IDTICKET;
        $json['NOMEFANTASIA'][] = $row -> NOMEFANTASIA;
        $json['PRECO'][] = $row -> PRECO1;
        $json['IDCARTAO'][] = $row -> IDCARTAO;
        echo json_encode($json['CODPRD']);
        echo json_encode($json['IDTICKET']);
        echo json_encode($json['NOMEFANTASIA']);

        // echo "".$json['CODPRD'];
    }

    /*if($json['CODPRD']){
    $string = implode(",",$json['CODPRD']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TPRODUTO where CODPRD = '{$string}'";
    $rc = ibase_query($con, $sql);
    while ($row = ibase_fetch_object($rc)) { 
      $json['NOMEFANTASIA'][] = $row -> NOMEFANTASIA;
      echo json_encode($json['NOMEFANTASIA']);

    }  */

    ibase_free_result($rc);
    ibase_close($con);
```

Então na hora que eu vou ver os dados no web aparecem da seguinte maneira

```
["000415"][3]["000415","001607"][3,23]["000415","001607","001609"][3,23,513]["000415","001607","001609","001475"][3,23,513,558]["000415","001607","001609","001475","001328"][3,23,513,558,558]["000415","001607","001609","001475","001328","001223"][3,23,513,558,558,681]["000415","001607","001609","001475","001328","001223","000743"][3,23,513,558,558,681,714]["000415","001607","001609","001475","001328","001223","000743","000270"][3,23,513,558,558,681,714,714]["000415","001607","001609","001475","001328","001223","000743","000270","000333"][3,23,513,558,558,681,714,714,714]
```

Já no firebird aparece mais organizado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu não estou sabendo como organizar pelos números predominantes, que é o `IDCARTÃO` e `IDTICKET`, existe uma maneira mais fácil de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro aperfeiçoar o seu código **SQL**:

```
SELECT tt.idticket, ttp.codprd, tp.nomefantasia, tp.preco1, tt.idcartao 
FROM TTICKET tt
INNER JOIN TTICKETPROD ttp
  ON ttp.idticket = tt.idticket
INNER JOIN TPRODUTO tp
  ON tp.codprd = ttp.codprd
WHERE tt.status = 'A'
ORDER BY tt.idticket ASC, ttp.codprd ASC
```

Você pode utilizar **apelidos** para sua tabela e utilizar o **ORDER BY** para organizar a ordem que é exibida seus dados, no caso ordenei de forma ascendente **ASC**, mas você pode ordenar de forma decrescente **DESC**.

Você também pode agrupar os dados, para isso basta informar os campos que deseja agrupar e somar os outros que vão fazer parte do agrupamento (os resultados) através do **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT tt.idticket, ttp.codprd, tp.nomefantasia, tt.idcartao 
SUM(tp.preco1) AS Total_precol
FROM TTICKET tt
INNER JOIN TTICKETPROD ttp
  ON ttp.idticket = tt.idticket
INNER JOIN TPRODUTO tp
  ON tp.codprd = ttp.codprd
WHERE tt.status = 'A'
GROUP BY tt.idticket, ttp.codprd, tp.nomefantasia, tt.idcartao 
ORDER BY tt.idticket ASC, ttp.codprd ASC
```

Nesse exemplo eu **agrupei** **(GROUP BY)** os campos tt.idticket, ttp.codprd, tp.nomefantasia, tt.idcartao e **somei** **(SUM)** o campo valor, note o **GROUP BY** no final do código.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema, agora estou quebrando a cabeça para agrupar, mas isso creio que com o tempo vou conseguir, abraços tudo de bom.